# Use :set for custom option in vim

Tags: vim

I currently have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:Myvar="noisy"

function Myfirstfunction()
    if g:Myvar=="noisy"
    echo "noisy"
   else
    echo "quiet"
   endif
endfunction
```

I would like to be able to change (or toggle) `g:Myvar` using `:set`

```
:set g:Myvar=quiet
```

Of course, the current set up doesn't work, hence the question: how can I toggle a custom option using `:set`? I'm not convinced that my approach so far is valid, so I am very open to it being overhauled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let g:Variable = "noisy"

function! MyFirstFunction()
if g:Variable == "noisy"
    echo "noisy"
else
    echo "quiet"
endif
endfunction
```

I don't see the problem with the above. "It works on my machine" :) But, I'm not quite sure what exactly are you asking next - `let g:Variable="quiet"` works also. 
Are you asking how to make function that will toggle one variable between two different values?

```
let g:Variable = 1

function! TogglingVariable()
if g:Variable == 1
    let g:Variable = 0
    echo "Variable is now 0"
else
    let g:Variable = 1
    echo "Variable is now 1"
endif
endfunction
```

If neither of these is what you want, you'll have to explain it a bit more then. This is all I could conclude from the question.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer Idigas, sorry if my question wasn't clear :) As you say, the code I posted works- I would like to be able to change the value of `g:Variable` using `:set g:Variable=quiet`. If that's not possible, then your answer does give me some other ideas though :)

Comment: @cmhughes - Glad to hear I got at least some of it right :) First, "quiet" is a string, therefore it should be in quotes. Second, there is a difference between :set and :let; :let is somewhat more flexible, I recommend using that one. Apart from that, they do the same thing. Try to expand a bit on your answer further, if something is still not clear and I'll do my best to help in what I can.

Comment: Thanks again. Your `TogglingVariable()` function does the trick using `call TogglingVariable()` which is what I wanted to do. Sorry that my question wasn't clear :)

Comment: What is the role of the exclamation in 'function! TogglingVariable()'?0

Comment: @Ronin420 - It enables the function to get "overwritten" i.e. reloaded the next time you source it. Were there not an exclamation Vim would give an error that that function already exists. A function by that name, at least.